# Parsing a text file, add text in it and save to another file - Java

Tags: java, parsing

I have a txt file with this format:

```
20/03/2013  23:31:36    6890    6810    6810    6730    6870    6680    6670    6700    6740    6810    34880   34336
```

What i want to do is enter some text between the values, obtaining this type of file:

`"somestring" "date(possibly converted in unix epoch time)" "objectA=6890" "objectB=6810" ...` and so on

I don't know what could be the best solution (also in terms of time of executing) in Java Programming, especially for files who have a lot of lines,

Thank You

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Do you have fix data to add at each value ???

Comment: @Ravi Not yet, i can parse a file, i don't know if there are some APIs about insert text between lines

Comment: you can do it by replacing 4-size spaces with 3-size space and prefix for values by replaceAll() method

Comment: Could be "scanner" a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the use of `Scanner` method. First i will parse everything and then i'll put all in an arraylist. The solution i found:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("filepath"));
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (s.hasNext()){
    list.add(s.next());
}
s.close();
```

Then i will analyze the arraylist and modify it with some print and concatenation (due to fact that my data is regular)